# Split function in objective-c (card game)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i'm beginner in objective c, i'm creating a card game for iPhone and I've a problem with a function: I create a deck of cards, shuffle it and now I need to split the deck in 4 hands (for the 4 players)

Here is my function :

```
-(void) split(int i1, int i2, int i3) 
{
    NSMutableArray *list1;
    NSMutableArray *list2;
    NSMutableArray *list3;
    NSMutableArray *list4;

    int a =0; 

    for(int i =0;i<i1;i++){
        list1 [i]=cards[a];
        a++;
    }
    for(int i =0;i<i1;i++){
        list2 [i]=cards[a];
        a++;
    }
    for(int i =0;i<i1;i++){
        list3 [i]=cards[a];
        a++;
    }
    for(int i =0;i<i1;i++){
        list4 [i]=cards[a];
        a++;
    }


    for(int i =i1;i<i1+i2;i++){
        list1 [i]=cards[a];
        a++;
    }
    for(int i =i1;i<i1+i2;i++){
        list2 [i]=cards[a];
        a++;
    }
    for(int i =i1;i<i1+i2;i++){
        list3 [i]=cards[a];
        a++;
    }
    for(int i =i1;i<i1+i2;i++){
        list4 [i]=cards[a];
        a++;
    }


    for(int i =i1+i2;i<i1+i2=i3;i++){
        list1 [i]=cards[a];
        a++;
    }
    for(int i =i1+i2;i<i1+i2=i3;i++){
        list2 [i]=cards[a];
        a++;
    }
    for(int i =i1+i2;i<i1+i2=i3;i++){
        list3 [i]=cards[a];
        a++;
    }
    for(int i =i1+i2;i<i1+i2=i3;i++){
        list4 [i]=cards[a];
        a++;
    }

    }
```

I think I didn't declare it well 
Can someone tell me if you have an idea? (I know this problem is easy for you guys but right now I'm blocked)

Comment: does your code compile?  creating a series of (for int i = 0;...) loops (redeclaring a variable) is typically not allowed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (void) split:(int)i1 a:(int)i2 a:(int) i3 {}
```

Try googling some tutorials/examples for the ObjC syntax.

NSMutableArray arrays are not like C-Array's. 
You have to alloc/init them and use the NSMutableArray methods (See documentation)

Comment: tanks for your (fast) answer :)